# Changing the control parameters of Manipulate

Tags: manipulate

I am trying to adjust the start and end points of a Manipulate function using variables that only change value if a certain condition is met. What is wrong with the code below?

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];

Manipulate[

 If[True, xinit = 3; xMax = 5;

  , xinit=1; xMax=4;];

 x,

 {{x, xinit}, 1, xMax, 1}

 ]
```

Comment: remove semicolon after `xMax = 5`

Comment: Removing the semicolon still gave me an error...

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one way: make the range be a checkbox (to choose the desired range for the x variable). Also, place the xinit and xmax variables inside `Dynamic` so they react to the changed values.

```
Manipulate[If[range, xinit = 3; xMax = 5;, xinit = 1; xMax = 4;]; x, 
  {{x, Dynamic[xinit]}, 1, Dynamic[xMax], 1}, {range, {False, True}}]
```

Comment: YES making the parameter Dynamic[] is exactly what I needed!! Thanks so much!